# how to redirect a page in nodejs

Tags: node.js, redirect

Currently this doesnt work. I'm new to nodejs so maybe the format is completely wrong

```
function blueScreen(showit) {
   console.log(showit);
   if (showit) {
      function getFormattedUrl(req) {
         return url.format({
           protocol: req.protocol,
           host: req.get('localhost:3000/blue.html')
         });
      }
   }
   return res.redirect(getFormattedUrl(req));;
}
```

I do know this goes into this function but the screen wont change when showIt is true
UPDATE: the res.redirect i believe is wrong because i never defined rec anyway. However I will say that this is not in the same file the app is due to the way my files interact it cant be in that file. Is there a way I can redirect my screen in a file without req and res function?

Comment: where does come from the `res` and `req` variable ?

Comment: i suppose the req is from the parameter of getFormattedUrl but i am not sure where i got res, it was just something i found online, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you use `expressjs`. Basically you have a middleware function where you can access to the **request response** object

```
app.get('/blue', function (req, res) {
   res.redirect('/green');
});
```

Comment: i dont use app in this file, how do i export it?

Comment: can you see us you file ? Don't you have `var app = express();` ?

Comment: Yes I have that but it's located in a different file

Comment: so you can juste add it to your file

Comment: Will it be ok since it's not the same app? Is there an issue with that?

Comment: Will there be some kind of communication issue since I'm making a new app?

Comment: you are right, maybe you should use the routing system with `express.Router` (see this link : http://expressjs.com/fr/guide/routing.html)